# How to override a controller for submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

> Scenario

I have got four resources in my Rails project, viz. Drive, Drivecomment, College and Manager

```
resources :drives do 
    resources :drivecomments
  end

devise_for :colleges, controllers: { sessions: "college/sessions", registrations: "college/registrations" }
devise_for :managers, controllers: { sessions: "manager/sessions", registrations: "manager/registrations" }
```

The association between them are as follows:

```
Manager => belongs_to :college

College => has_many :managers
College => has_many :drives

Drives => belongs_to :college
Drives => has_many :drivecomments

Drivecomments => belongs_to :drives
```

As it is clear from above association, each Drive can have multiple Drivecomments, which can be submitted by the Managers.

Also, I have created a custom Controller#View resource "m" for providing a Manager Interface (coz default manager is generated from devise and using the same resource means all post operations get redirected to "create" method, including sign_up, which eventually means i cannot sign_up at all)

```
resources :m, :only => [:index] do
    member do
      get :drive
    end
  end
```

So, inside my "m", I have created a form for posting a comment as well as a table for displaying all comments.

FOR DISPLAYING COMMENTS:

```
../drive.html.erb
<h2>Drive Comments</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Jobseeker</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.jobseeker.first_name  %></td>
        <td><%= comment.title %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

../m_controller.erb
def drive
    @drive = @drives.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @comments = @drive.drivecomments
    @addcomment = Drivecomment.new
end
```

FOR ADDING A COMMENT:

```
../drive.html.erb
<%= form_for [@addcomment], as: :addcomment, url: {action: "addcomment"} do |f| %>

    <div><%= f.hidden_field :drive_id, :value => @drive.id %></div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :jobseeker_id, :value => 2 %></div>

    <div><%= f.label "Comment:" %><%= f.text_field :title %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Post Comment" %></div>
  <% end %>

../m_controller.erb
  def new
    @addcomment = Drivecomment.new
  end

  def create
    @drive = @drives.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @addcomment = @drive.drivecomments.build
    @addcomment.save
  end
```

> Problem

When I submit my form, I get an error saying

## ActionController::UrlGenerationError in M#drive

Showing /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/app/views/m/drive.html.erb where line #30 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"addcomment", :controller=>"m", :id=>"5"}

Extracted source (around line #30):

```
</table>

<%= form_for [@addcomment], as: :addcomment, url: {action: "addcomment"} do |f| %>

    <div><%= f.hidden_field :drive_id, :value => @drive.id %></div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :jobseeker_id, :value => 2 %></div>
```

Alternatively, If I write my form like this

```
<%= form_for [@drive, @addcomment] do |f| %>

    <div><%= f.hidden_field :drive_id, :value => @drive.id %></div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :jobseeker_id, :value => 2 %></div>

    <div><%= f.label "Comment:" %><%= f.text_field :title %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Post Comment" %></div>
<% end %>
```

it submits the form successfully and a value gets added, but I get redirected to "http://localhost:3000/drives/5/drivecomments/8" from "http://localhost:3000/m/5/drive" which I don't want.
Please tell what might be the workaround for this problem.

> Additional Info

Drivecomments _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@drive, @drivecomment]) do |f| %>
  <% if @drivecomment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@drivecomment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this drivecomment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @drivecomment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :jobseeker_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :jobseeker_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :drive_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :drive_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Extract from drivecoments_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_drivecomment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :load_drive

def new
     @drivecomment = @drive.drivecomments.new
end

def create
    @drivecomment = @drive.drivecomments.new(drivecomment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @drivecomment.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@drive, @drivecomment], notice: 'Drivecomment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @drivecomment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @drivecomment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_drivecomment
      @drivecomment = Drivecomment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def drivecomment_params
      params.require(:drivecomment).permit(:jobseeker_id, :drive_id, :title)
    end

    def load_drive
       @drive = Drive.find(params[:drive_id])
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to user the action `create` from the controller `m` you should define your form like this:

```
<%= form_for @addcomment, url: url_for(controller: :m, action: :create) do |f| %>
```

Also, you need to define the `create` action on your routes, update this piece of your routes:

```
resources :m, :only => [:index,  :create]
```

Comment: You need to define the route for the create action too. I updated my answer

Comment: Hey azk92, thanks for that, really. But when I submit my comment, it shows the error
"undefined method `drivecomments' for nil:NilClass". Can you please tell me how to extract [:id] from the url?   I tried doing @drive = @drives.find_by_id(params[:id]), but that didn't work. Is it because I added my own member? Should I have gone for a nested resource? Please suggest

Comment: Finally did this... Yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Added "@drive = @drives.find_by_id(params[:drivecomment][:drive_id])" in my controller to extract the drive_id. Thanks a bunch :)